# Cannot implicitly convert 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to create a simple EnemyAI where the enemy follows the player. I have problem where the Engine cannot convert 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'. Here's the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyAI : MonoBehaviour
{
    Transform TargetedPlayer;
    public float EnemySpeed = 3f;
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        EnemyFollow();
    }
    void EnemyFollow()
    {
        TargetedPlayer = GameObject.Find("Pig"); //Issue
        if (Vector3.Distance(transform.position,TargetedPlayer.position)>1f)
        {
            transform.Translate(new Vector3(EnemySpeed * Time.deltaTime,0,0) );
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the problem but I don't know how to change the code without breaking it. **Thanks In Advance to the people that helped :)**

Comment: Well, the error sounds quite self-explanatory ... `GameObject.Find` returns a `GameObject` .. so you want `TargetedPlayer = GameObject.Find("Pig").transform;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a wild guess here but make

```
[SerializeField] Transform TargetedPlayer;
```

or

`public Transform TargetedPlayer;`

and drag the player there

and delete

```
TargetedPlayer = GameObject.Find("Pig"); //Issue
```

In my little experience I would recommend you if you can, use NavMeshAgent for the enemy to follow the player